# How to compare originalList to filterList in recyclerview using Filter?

Tags: java, android, filter, android-edittext, android-filterable

In this code I have search multiple text ex. I have search sachin.

sachin is show the list but click to back sachin to sac not display to sa list on adapter. How to solve it without any library?

when I press back space and remove a char this time dos not list not display.
Example

Suppose I have search sachin to text change sachin to sac. In this case not display sa list. I have clear all list that case display all list.

search sa show the list 

sachin and sardar

now search sac

now display the sachin

search only sac to sc 

that's time display only sachin 

 not disply the sardar in the list

My Adapter

```
private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Build> buildlist = new ArrayList<Build>();


            for (int i = 0; i < buildList.size(); i++) {
                if ((buildList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    Build babydata = new Build(buildList.get(i).getImages(), buildList.get(i).getName());

                    buildlist.add(babydata);
                }
            }
            results.count = buildlist.size();
            results.values = buildlist;

        } else {
            results.count = buildList.size();
            results.values = buildList;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        buildList = (ArrayList<Build>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Activity class

```
 EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (s.length() <= 0) {
                Log.d("jay", "s.length() <= 0" + s.toString());
                buildList.clear();
                buildList.addAll(buildListCopy);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                buildCustomAdapter = new BuildCustomAdapter(buildList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(buildCustomAdapter);

            } else {
                buildCustomAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
            Log.d("jay", "mobisharnam" + s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: please try my answer given below, its very easy with predicate & faster than filter, you need to just copy & paste code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any Library simple logic

Finally I have solution in this question

In your Adapter Constructor add the new copy list

After the  copy list is add in filter

```
 private List<YourModel> modelList;
 private List<YourModel> modelListCopy;
 private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();


 public YourAdapter(List<YourModel> modelList) {
    this.modelList= modelList;
    this.modelListCopy= new ArrayList<>();
    modelListCopy.addAll(modelList);
}
private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            List<YourModel> filterList = new ArrayList<YourModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < modelListCopy.size(); i++) {
                if ((modelListCopy.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    YourModel builddata = new YourModel(modelListCopy.get(i).getImages(), modelListCopy.get(i).getName());
                    filterList.add(builddata);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;

        } else {
            results.count = modelListCopy.size();
            results.values = modelListCopy;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        modelList= (ArrayList<YourModel>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Activity Class

like this

```
 CustomAdapter youradapter= new CustomAdapter(modelList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Predicate for search filter
I have changed your code to use Predicate, You have to use google guava library for that
include following depedency in your gradle

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
```

now, check following code

```
EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String searchQuery = s.toString();
                if (buildListCopy != null && buildListCopy.size() > 0) {
                    buildList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(buildListCopy, new SearchFilter(searchQuery)));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                    if (buildList != null && buildList.size() > 0) {);
                        buildCustomAdapter = new BuildCustomAdapter(buildList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(buildCustomAdapter);
                        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Here is your search filter predicate which we have used above

```
/**
     * Custom Predicate class to filter list as per search query
     */
    public final class SearchFilter implements Predicate<Build> {
        private final Pattern pattern;

        public SearchFilter(final String regex) {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.LITERAL);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply(final Build input) {
            return pattern.matcher(input.getName().toLowerCase()).find();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Divyang any other logic withour use google guava library?

Comment: Why you have initialized buildlist & buildlist Copy in your ItemFilter class just above for loop, try after removing this both lines

Comment: Okay I will try this